# How do I calculate the product $a \cdot b \cdot c$ if $ 2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c = 270,000,000 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I calculate the product $a \cdot b \cdot c$ if

$$
2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c = 270,000,000
$$

I'm afraid I don't know the exponential rules properly. I know it is possible to do $2^a \cdot 3 \cdot 3^{b-1} \cdot ...$, but that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$270000000=27*10^{7}=3^3(2*5)^7=3^3*2^7*5^7$$